# How do I explicitly call an exception-throwing method in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a simple class:

```
class A {
 public:
  bool f(int* status = nullptr) noexcept {
    if (status) *status = 1;
    return true;
  }
  void f() {
    throw std::make_pair<int, bool>(1, true);
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.f(); // <- Ambiguity is here! I want to call 'void f()'
}
```

I want to resolve ambiguity of a method call in favour of the exception-throwing method by any means.

The rationale behind such interface:

- To have the `noexcept(true)` and `noexcept(false)` interface,
- To allow optionally get extra information via a pointer in the `noexcept(false)` variant - while the `noexcept(true)` variant will always pack this information inside an exception.

Is it possible at all? Suggestions for a better interface are also welcome.

Comment: If I recall correctly C++17 made `noexcept` part of the function type which would probably help if you weren't stuck in C++14.

Comment: Use different names for different functions.

Comment: As @n.m said, use different names. Explicit is good, implicit is bad. In general.

Comment: But if you absolutely want the same name interface, then since you have different signatures you can simply `static_cast` to the relevant function type. That's ugly. The ugliness is an indicator of ungoodness.

Comment: Remove the default argument from the `noexcept` variant, and problem solved?

Comment: You'd need different names. For example in Android we've got lots of `<method>OrThrow()` methods for `<method>()` methods.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto: No, you don't "need" different names, that's technically wrong. And what do Android Java methods have to do with the question?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well, that was an example of how you could name your method instead, and a good one. One could also use `trySomeAction` as method name. Also, the word "need" may be wrong in a technical sense, but in an aesthetic sense it makes sense.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Having functions with this kind of signatures is obviously a bad design as you've found out. The real solutions are to have different names for them or to lose the default argument and were presented already in other answers.

However if you are stuck with an interface you can't change or just for the fun of it here is how you can explicitly call `void f()`:

The trick is to use function pointer casting to resolve the ambiguity:

```
a.f(); // <- ambiguity is here! I want to call 'void f()'

(a.*(static_cast<void (A::*)()>(&A::f)))(); // yep... that's the syntax... yeah...
```

Ok, so it works, but **don't ever write code like this!**

There are ways to make it more readable.

#### Use a pointer:

```
// create a method pointer:
auto f_void = static_cast<void (A::*)()>(&A::f);

// the call is much much better, but still not as simple as `a.f()`
(a.*f_void)();
```

#### Create a lambda or a free function

```
auto f_void = [] (A& a)
{
    auto f_void = static_cast<void (A::*)()>(&A::f);
    (a.*f_void)();
};

// or

void f_void(A& a)
{
    auto f_void = static_cast<void (A::*)()>(&A::f);
    (a.*f_void)();
};


f_void(a);
```

I don't know if this is necessary better. The call syntax is definitely simpler, but it might be confusing as we are switching from a method call syntax to a free function call syntax.

Comment: The only answer that is answering the question instead of questioning the design.

Comment: @WorldSEnder Sometimes questioning the design is the correct answer, though. See also [Pounding A Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)

Comment: @WorldSEnder: The question explicitly says: *"Suggestions for a better interface are also welcome."*

Comment: @Angew I don't get your point. A [bologna bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_bottle) is literally made for that. ;-)

Comment: "Just for the fun of it", he said. `(a.*(void (A::*)())&A::f)();` is indeed funny :-D

Comment: This explains how to choose between ambiguous overloads based on the return types. But the title asks how to choose the `noexcept` one or not. Is that possible, or is the only way to achieve this to have different return types?

Comment: @KateGregory despite the use of the name `f_void` the disambiguation in this answer actually relies on the signature (parameter types), not the return type. And, while it allows calling the exception throwing (parameterless) variant, it doesn't allow calling the `noexcept` variant, except by providing a parameter. Which IMHO makes my answer much better. :)

Answer (score 28):

Both versions `f` have different meanings.

They should have two different name, as:

- `f` for the throwing one, because using it means that your are confident on success, and failure would be an exception in the program.
- `try_f()` or `tryF()` for the error-return based one, because using it means that failure of the call is an expected outcome.

Two different meanings should be reflected in the design with two different name.

Comment: That's a good design decision and eliminates any ambiguity on the call site. The caller doesn't need to rely on the language to infer the correct overload, but rather is very explicit about what they're trying to do.

Answer (score 16):

Because it seems fundamentally obvious to me, I may be missing something or may not fully understand your question. However, I think this does exactly what you want:

```
#include <utility>

class A {
 public:
  bool f(int* status) noexcept {
    if (status) *status = 1;
    return true;
  }
  void f() {
    throw std::make_pair<int, bool>(1, true);
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.f(); // <- now calls 'void f()'
  a.f(nullptr);  // calls 'bool f(int *)'
}
```

I simply removed the default argument from the `noexcept` variant. It's still possible to call the `noexcept` variant by passing `nullptr` as an argument, which seems a perfectly fine way of indicating that you want to call that particular variant of the function - after all, there's going to have to be *some* syntactic marker indicating which variant you want to call!

Answer (score 5):

I agree with other users' suggestions to simply remove the default argument.

A strong argument in favour of such a design is that it would be in line with the new C++17 filesystem library, whose functions typically offer callers the choice between exceptions and error reference parameters.

See for example [`std::filesystem::file_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size), which has two overloads, one of them being `noexcept`:

> ```
> std::uintmax_t file_size( const std::filesystem::path& p );
>
> std::uintmax_t file_size( const std::filesystem::path& p,
>                           std::error_code& ec ) noexcept;
> ```

The idea behind this design (which is originally from Boost.Filesystem) is almost identical to yours, except of the default argument. Remove it and you do it like a brand new component of the standard library, which obviously can be expected not to have a completely broken design.

Answer (score 2):

In C++14 it's ambiguous because `noexcept` is *not* part of the function signature. With that said...

You have a very strange interface. Although `f(int* status = nullptr)` is labelled `noexcept`, because it has a twin that *does* throw a exception, you are not really giving the caller a logical exception guarantee. It seems you simultaneously want `f` to *always succeed* while throwing an exception if the precondition is not met (status has a valid value, i.e not `nullptr`). But if `f` throws, what state is the object in? You see, your code is very hard to reason about.

I recommend you take a look at [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) instead. It'll signal to the reader what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Not a bad answer, but the first sentence is kind of misleading. The ambiguity is not just because `noexcept` isn't part of the function signature. The code still fails in C++17 where `noexcept` _is_ part of the function signature, because the call is still ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

C++ already has a type specifically used as an argument to disambiguate between throwing and non-throwing variants of a function: `std::nothrow_t`. You can use that.

```
#include <new>

class A {
 public:
  bool f(std::nothrow_t, int* status = nullptr) noexcept {
    if (status) *status = 1;
    return true;
  }
  void f() {
    throw std::make_pair<int, bool>(1, true);
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.f(); // Calls 'void f()'
  a.f(std::nothrow); // Calls 'void f(std::nothrow_t, int*)'
}
```

Though I would still prefer an interface where the name distinguishes the variants, or possibly one where the distinction isn't necessary.

Comment: But that type is only meant to be used with dynamic memory allocation functions. While it's technically possible to use it for something else, I wonder if that doesn't create too much confusion.

Comment: @ChristianHackl IMO, the only confusion here is that you have to include `<new>`. Nothing else in the type indicates its intended use.

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a *purely compile-time* method.

It may be useful if your compiler happens to have trouble optimizing away function pointer calls.

```
#include <utility>

class A {
 public:
  bool f(int* status = nullptr) noexcept {
    if (status) *status = 1;
    return true;
  }
  void f() {
    throw std::make_pair<int, bool>(1, true);
  }
};

template<void (A::*F)()>
struct NullaryFunction {
  static void invoke(A &obj) {
    return (obj.*F)();
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  // a.f(); // <- Ambiguity is here! I want to call 'void f()'
  NullaryFunction<&A::f>::invoke(a);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

So you are trying to throw an exception if the code is unprepared for an error return?

Then, how about

```
class ret
{
    bool success;
    mutable bool checked;
    int code;
public:
    ret(bool success, int code) : success(success), checked(false), code(code) { }
    ~ret() { if(!checked) if(!success) throw code; }

    operator void *() const { checked = true; return reinterpret_cast<void *>(success); }
    bool operator!() const { checked = true; return !success; }

    int code() const { return code; }
};
```

This is still an [Abomination unto Nuggan](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Abominations_Unto_Nuggan) though.

By removing the `if(!success)` check in the destructor, you can make the code throw whenever a return code is not looked at.

Comment: This is a classic C++ mistake: never throw from a destructor. The problem is, what if some other code throws an exception after a `ret` object is created but before the return code is checked? Then, as the stack is unwound, the destructor for `ret` will be called, throwing another exception, and the process will `abort()`.

Comment: @ArthurTacca, I totally agree that the code is horrible. It's something I would use as a temporary measure during refactoring, but edit out of the commits before pushing.